# Как пользоваться aiogram не в режиме ответа?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Возможно ли использовать библиотеку **aiogram** в асинхронном режиме просто выполняя методы? Не только в качестве ответа для пользователя.

Условный код:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
bot = Bot(token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
await bot.send_message(54656484, 'text')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
await bot.send_message(user_id, text)
```

разово выполняется так

```
import asyncio
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(bot.send_message(user_id, text))
```

Comment: я не вижу чатов в вашем примере, дополните вопрос - исправлю.

Comment: Всё работает, но выводит предупреждение:
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x00000000049AB9A0>
Unclosed connector
connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x0000000003CD6640>, 50036.275)]']
connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x00000000049AB8B0>

Его можно как-нибудь отключить?